# ERROR : Java Constructor for "net.sf.sahi.plugin.DBClient" with Arguments "string,string,string,string" Not Found

Tags: jdbc, odbc, sahi

I am a beginner in Sahi Automation Tool.

I set the following changes to run my script.

1) In Sahi/Userdata/bin
SET SAHI_EXT_CLASS_PATH=%EXT_CLASS_PATH%;d:\Sahi\extlib\db\mysql_connector_java_5.1.34_bin.jar;

2) Downloaded and installed the 64 bit ODBC drivers (AccessDatabaseEngine.exe)

3) Set the proxy and port in userdata.properties

Here is my code.

---

```
var db = _getDB("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver","jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver(*.xlsx)};DBQ=d:\\Sahi\\userdata\\scripts\\My_works\\Login.xlsx;readOnly=false","","");
if(db != null)
{
var $rs = db.select("select * from [Sheet1$]");
}
```

---

I am encountering below ERROR.

**--Stopped Playback: FAILURE--**

Kindly help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lissy, I would suggest you not to use db APIs to work with the excel files. [_getExcel](http://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/excel-apis.html#_getExcel) and [_readExcelFile](http://sahipro.com/docs/sahi-apis/excel-apis.html#_readExcelFile) should work perfectly for you.

Comment: Actually I tried that also. But again i am getting same error. Is any jars or anything to be installed to work this? please help

Comment: Do you mean to say that you are not able to work with _getExcel and _readExcelFile as well?`var $rs = _readExcelFile("d:\\Sahi\\userdata\\scripts\\My_works\\Login.xlsx", "Sheet1");`
should be working for you.

Comment: Getting an ERROR
ReferenceError: "_readExcelFile" is not defined. **Please help**

Comment: Looks like you are a Sahi OS user (If so, then I wont be able to help you out much with it)
or
you upgraded Sahi Pro recently (If so, then do a fresh installation as this is looks like an upgradation issue), right?